# after click on link javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

when I click on link and I want to add class not working
i want do (div modal )

code php/html

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['ido']) )
     {
    ?>
  <div id ="modal" class="modal" style="background: blue; width: 100%; 
     height: 180%">
    <div class="modal2" >

     </div>
   </div>
   <?php 
   }
      ?>
<div id="no" class="no" style="width: 100%;height: 300%;background: #000">
    <div class="nolink" style="width: 50%;height: 50%;margin: 0 auto ; background: #fff">
        <span> 
            <a href="?ido=22" id="link">link </a>
         </span>

    </div>

</div>
```

code javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById('link').onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById('modal').classList.add('new') ; 
    };

</script>
```

when I click on link and I want to add class not working
i want do (div modal )

Comment: This code works fine? The only thing you can do is remove the '?ido=22' to '#', so that the javascript will actually execute.

Comment: but i want that ?ido=22'

Comment: You're leaving the page and reload it just after having changed the class, of course you can't see the result. What's your exact goal ?

Comment: use php to check if get ?ido=22 and then add class?

Comment: my goal just to do a modal (overlay), each user read the article on the page just on link url (article id)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add new class on click, you should remove php condition and add 'return false' in onClick function

something like this:  https://codepen.io/tuzov/pen/OQWJzB

```js
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById('modal').classList.add('new') ; 
  return false;
};
```

```css
.modal {
  display:none;
}
.modal.new {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id ="modal" class="modal" style="background: blue; width: 100%; 
     height: 180%">
    <div class="modal2" >
123
     </div>
   </div>

<div id="no" class="no" style="width: 100%;height: 300%;background: #000">
    <div class="nolink" style="width: 50%;height: 50%;margin: 0 auto ; background: #fff">
        <span> 
            <a href="?ido=22" id="link">link </a>
         </span>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="?ido=22" id="link">link </a>
```

Your code is fine. The problem here is href in link (?ido=22). try to replace it with other options. and

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('link').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('modal').classList.add('new') ; 
};
```

if you use return false inside click function your link will not work. Be aware of that.